# WPF DataGridTextColumn binding and style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

here's the deal: styling the DataGridTextColumn's textblock for a datagrid.
I need to format the textblock by it's value, by comparing it from another binded value.

What i want to achieve is something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ExpeditionerCellStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BEST}" Value="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Which is not possible, because the Value of Datatrigger cannot be a relative source.

So i tried with multibinding

```
<Style x:Key="ExpeditionerCellStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
 <Style.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsValueEqualParameterConverter}">
        <Binding Path="BEST" />
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
      </MultiBinding>
     </DataTrigger.Binding>
    </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

with no luck: textblock Text property is empty, probably because the style is applied before the actual binding is performed.

I have no more ideas.

Please help me!

Comment: Please try to explain your requirements more clearly.

Comment: I need to compare the value of DataGridTextColumn's textblock with another binding. Why the textblock is always empty?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but I noticed that you forgot to specify the `Binding.Path` in your `MultiConverter` example... try this:

```
<Style x:Key="ExpeditionerCellStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsValueEqualParameterConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="BEST" />
                    <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: nope, with binding path return the textblock itself, still without text valorized

Comment: How can you get the same result? If the first result was the whole `TextBlock`, how can you still get that when the `Path` is now pointing to the `Text` property? Are you looking at the values that come into the `Converter`?

Comment: I'm sorry. With same result i inteded that the texblock text property is still empty.
I bet it's because at the time the style is parsed, data isn't still really binded to the control

Comment: Well if I were you, I'd ensure that there was data shown in the control *before* you try writing any `Trigger`s that require that data to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the style of the textblock based on the content of the textblock why not just add a bidning to the textblock background and use a converter to check the content of the text?

In other words bind both the text and the background to the same source and use a converter with the background and in the converter match the content and return the correct background style.

If you need something else leave a comment so we better know what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is, that I can only rely on runtime value. This style is tied to multiple columns.

Comment: Well that depends on if the style is dependent on several properties from the same underlying object you could bind the style to the object itself and check all properties. And as regarding to runtime all converters is used runtime...

Answer (score 0):

I ended modifying a bit my code.
Instead of relying on the value of the cell, in the field "BEST" i passed the name of the column. 
Then using the converter I check
Current textblock (as suggested by @Sheridan) -> DatagridCell -> Column's header
if it match, i change the style on this textblock.

Thanks everyone!!!